# Malloc error - can't assign to variable sized object

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

For the malloc statement below, I am failing to initialize a variable-sized object

```
int textsize = BUF_SIZE;
  char *lines[textsize] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * textsize);
```

The objective is to have an array of pointers where each will store the pointers to STDIN lines entered by the user.
textsize is the number of lines that is supported as input by the user.

Error:

```
error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
    char *lines[textsize] = malloc(sizeof(char *) * textsize);
```

Comment: You're trying to dynamically allocate an array you've already statically allocated. `char **lines = malloc(sizeof(char *) * textsize);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have allocated the lines with textsize as a size:- static, and then you are trying to allocate dynamically using malloc..
Try double pointer

char **lines = malloc(...)

Comment: The problem with that is when later downstream in the code I do this:

while ((line = fgets(text, BUF_SIZE, stdin)) != NULL) {
 
lines[linecount] = line;
        ++linecount;
}

It will overwrite the lines[ ] in each iteration. I want to be able to save all athe sentences that come from the command prompt.

Comment: Replacement is because you are using '=' this will make lines[linecount] to point to line, and 'line' will change with while loop, you can instead use strcpy()
strcpy(lines[linecount], line)

here is code example:-

Comment: while ((textbuff = fgets(textbuff, textsize, stdin)) != NULL) {  
        if(textbuff[0] == '\n'){
            break;
        }
        line[linesCount] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char *) * strlen(textbuff));
        strcpy(line[linesCount], textbuff);
        linesCount ++;
    }

Answer (score 0):

As @A.Shenoy mentioned, you should use a double pointer. The reason for that is when you do `char *lines[textsize]`, you're creating a pointer to a char array, but malloc returns a char pointer. So the solution is to do `char **lines` which creates a pointer to a char pointer. You still need to allocate space for the pointers, this is how you can initialize the array;

```c
#define ARRAY_SIZE 5 // array of 5 strings

char **lines = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * ARRAY_SIZE);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
  lines[i] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * textsize);
}

// The array is now allocated, and you can fill it with strcpy

// Example for filling:
char text[] = "Hello World!";
strcpy(lines[0], text);
```